# Extent reports 4.0.3 - capture screenshot not working - c#, specflow

Tags: c#, specflow, extentreports

I am trying to add screenshot capture to extent report. I am able to capture screenshot using selenium webdriver but attaching screenshot to extent report is not working.

Code in `[AfterStep]` hook will actually generate step for failure in report. I have not included the code for pass step.

```
step.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath)
```

code runs successfully but the cannot find the attachment in report.

This is Hooks code trying to generate report for BDD feature.

```
    //Global Variable for Extend report
    private static ExtentTest featureName;
    private static ExtentTest scenario;
    private static ExtentTest step;
    private static ExtentReports extent;

    //Initialize extent reports
    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void InitializeReport()
    {
    //initialize extent report before test starts
    string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(assemblyFolder + "\\Reports\\ExtentReport.html");
    htmlReporter.Config.Theme = AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration.Theme.Dark;

    //Attach report to reporter
    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
    }

    //generate feature name dynamically
    [BeforeFeature]
    public static void BeforeFeature()
    {
    //Create dynamic feature name
    featureName = extent.CreateTest<Feature>(FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title);
    }

   //generate scenario name dynamically
    [BeforeScenario]
    public void Initialize()
    {

    //Create dynamic scenario name
    scenario = featureName.CreateNode<Scenario>(ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title);
    }

//get the screenshot upon failure
[AfterStep]
public void InsertReportingSteps()
{

    var stepType = ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.StepDefinitionType.ToString();
    PropertyInfo pInfo = typeof(ScenarioContext).GetProperty("ScenarioExecutionStatus", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    MethodInfo getter = pInfo.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
    object TestResult = getter.Invoke(ScenarioContext.Current, null);

    if (ScenarioContext.Current.TestError != null)
    {
        if (stepType == "Given"){
            step = scenario.CreateNode<Given>(stepType + " " + ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError.Message);
        }
        else if (stepType == "When"){
            step = scenario.CreateNode<When>(stepType + " " + ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError.Message);
        }
        else if (stepType == "Then"){
            step = scenario.CreateNode<Then>(stepType + " " + ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError.Message);
        }
        string screenshotPath = CaptureScreenshot.Capture(driver);

        //Capture screenshot not attaching screenshot to extent reports
        step.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath);
    }

}
   //flush extent reports
    [AfterTestRun]
    public static void TearDownReport()
    {
    //Flush report once test completes
    extent.Flush();
    }

class CaptureScreenshot
    {
        public static string Capture(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            ITakesScreenshot ts = (ITakesScreenshot)driver;
            Screenshot screenshot = ts.GetScreenshot();
            string screenShotName = "screenShotName_" + Calendar.getCurrentDate();
            string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string finalpth = assemblyFolder + "\\Reports\\Screenshots\\";
            string screenshotDir = finalpth + screenShotName + ".png";
            string localpath = new Uri(screenshotDir).LocalPath;
            screenshot.SaveAsFile(localpath);
            return localpath;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is an exception being thrown? What do you mean by "code runs successfully but the cannot find the attachment in report"?

Comment: @Greg, I mean step.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath); This particular line of code executed successfully, there was no exception being thrown. However, ExtentReports doesn't have the screenshot attachment.

Comment: What is your unit test provider? in your app.config file, do you have the following configuration?   <specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
  </specFlow>

Comment: Was there a resolution to this? I have exactly the same problem - the code (AddScreenCaptureFromPath) runs with no errors but the screenshot is not appended to the report

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by using MediaEntityBuilder

https://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/

```
MediaModelProvider mediaModel = 
MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath("screenshot.png").build();
test.fail("details", mediaModel);

// or:
test.fail("details", 
MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath("screenshot.png").build());
```

You'll need to include the screenshot in your step

```
step = scenario.CreateNode<Then>(stepType + " " + ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError.Message,MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath).Build());
```